# Можно ли избавиться от задержек в ffmpeg при показе mp4-видео?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

Я тут соорудил такой тестовый скрипт, который поштучно генерирует RGB-кадры в стандартный вывод:

```py
import sys
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

w, h = 32, 18
font = ImageFont.load_default()
with Image.new("RGB", (w, h), (0, 0, 0)) as im:
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

    frameno = 1
    while True:
        # Очищаем картинку от предыдущего номера кадра
        draw.rectangle((0, 0, w - 1, h - 1), fill=(0, 0, 0))
        # Рисуем номер текущего кадра
        draw.text((2, 2), str(frameno), font=font, fill=(255, 255, 255))

        # Выводим картинку в stdout
        with im.resize((w * 10, h * 10), resample=Image.NEAREST) as im_big:
            sys.stdout.buffer.write(im_big.tobytes())
        sys.stdout.buffer.flush()

        # Позволяем пользователю контролировать вывод покадрово с клавиатуры
        # (и заодно выводим номер текущего кадра в консоль для сравнения)
        if frameno >= 60:
            print(f"{frameno}>", file=sys.stderr, end=" ", flush=True)
            if input("").lower().strip() == "q":
                break
        frameno += 1
```

И составил такую цепочку для экспериментов с видеопотоком. Первый ffmpeg кодирует кадры из скрипта в H.264, пакует в mp4 и как бы «стримит видео», второй ffmpeg как бы «зритель» и смотрит этот видеопоток:

```sh
python framegen.py \
  | ffmpeg -loglevel error -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -s 320x180 -i - \
      -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -tune zerolatency \
      -f mp4 -movflags +frag_every_frame+empty_moov -flush_packets 1 - \
  | ffmpeg -loglevel error -f mp4 -i - \
      -pix_fmt rgb24 -f sdl2 -
```

По итогам я получил:

- скрипт выводит кадры мгновенно после их создания (неудивительно, я ж flush сделал);
- первый ffmpeg добавляет задержку в 1 кадр (если судить по выводу в mp4-файл и его последующему анализу);
- второй ffmpeg добавляет задержку ещё в 4 кадра (sdl2-вывод вроде не виноват, задержка возникает где-то на входе).

В связи с этим возникают вопросы:

1. Почему первый ffmpeg добавляет задержку в 1 кадр?
2. Почему второй ffmpeg добавляет задержку в 4 кадра?
3. Можно ли поиграться с опциями ffmpeg и/или настройками libx264 так, чтобы задержка получилась 0 кадров и нарисованный скриптом кадр выводился сразу? Ну или ладно, 1 кадр хотя бы...

---

UPD: обнаружил [похожий вопрос про h264 на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60462840), из которого следует, что использование формата `flv` с `-flags low_delay` даёт полное отсутствие задержки. Это очень круто, но вообще тот вопрос не совсем про `mp4` и не поясняет, что с этим форматом не так, так что в принципе вопрос ещё можно считать открытым